# How convert old version 2.2 .ma files to .nb notebooks?

Tags: bugs, notebooks, crash, conversion, history

I have a lot of old *Mathematica* version 2.2 `.ma` files that simply crash the current (10.4.1) version of *Mathematica* if I try to open them.

Is there some way to convert them to `.nb` notebook files?

Is 5.2 the latest version that will do the conversion? And if so, will that older version run under: Windows 10?  Windows 7?  OS X 10.11?

Comment: Probably not a practical approach for most people, but I always have version 5.2 installed on a computer I'm using. Its ability to fusslessly deal with *.ma files is one among many reasons why I keep it around.

Comment: Does version 5.2 run on a Mac under OS X El Capitan (10.11)? on a PC running Windows 10?

Comment: @J.M. I have a soft spot for 5.2. I *liked* that release.

Comment: Is 5.2 the latest version that will do the conversion?

Comment: I can confirm that 5.2 runs on Windows 10.

Comment: @RunnyKine: Is that on Windows 10 64-bit? (That's what I have.)

Comment: Yes, does anybody still use 32bit? :)

Comment: @Runny, hey, my netbook is 32-bit, you insensitive clod! :P (But seriously, I'll jump on the 64-bit bandwagon soon as I can afford to do so.)

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for making me laugh so hard. :)

Comment: @J.M. - I do most of my responses here on an old 32-bit netbook (treated as a throw-away, since the smoke from the cigars maims the insides eventually), and I personally enjoy the challenge of making things fast on a low core count, low clock, small RAM system - fast there means (usually) *really* fast elsewhere...

Comment: @ciao, heh, my netbook is where I do most of my artwork, as seen on my Gravatars. Takes quite a while, of course, but it works. I'm used to pinching shoes; a long while ago I was trying to implement numerical algorithms on an old Texas Instruments programmable calculator as an exercise. ;)

Answer (score 9):

[This](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2012/May/msg00371.html) [MathGroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica) discussion should answer your question, so I'll cite it here:

> On Tue, 29 May 2012 05:47:52 -0400 (EDT), JCW wrote:
>
> > Please forgive my dragging up ancient history: I have been using
> >     Mathematica
> >     from version 2.2 through 7.0. I remember at least one (maybe two?) format
> >     conversions that were necessary to update old notebooks to the newer
> >     formats. I also remember at least one batch-notebook-conversion command.
> >     Unfortunately I cannot remember the details:
> >
> > 1) Between which versions did these format changes occur? (I'm pretty
> >     sure there was one from the vs. 2.2 x.ma and x.mb format to the newer
> >     x.nb format. Was there another format change within x.nb versions?)
> >
> > 2) What was the name of the batch converter (or converters) mentioned
> >     above? (I know I have it in my archives, but it's difficult to find
> >     without a name!)
> >
> > Thanks in advance for any help!
>
> I'm always one for ancient history.
>
> There was only the one switch from 2.2 .ma/.mb files to 3.0 .nb files.
>   Possibly, you might be remembering v6 when pre-v6 notebooks were
>   opened with an  compatibility tool added to the top, but the tool had
>   nothing to do with the file format...it was merely an aid to updating
>   some of the code inside the  notebook.
>
> Also, .nb files are not wholly backward compatible.  They'll always
>   open in older versions, but as new features get added to Mathematica,
>   inputs/outputs depending upon those features may not render or
>   function correctly in older versions.  The most radical such change
>   would be in v6, when we switched from  using PostScript for graphics
>   to more native constructs in the notebooks. Which  means that pretty
>   much any v6 or later notebook is going to produce graphics which are
>   wholly unusable by v5 or earlier (but the notebooks *do* open, and
>   textual content comes through just fine).
>
> The converter for .ma->.nb is `` Developer`NotebookConvert ``.  It's still
>   documented  in the latest shipping Mathematica.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> John Fultz
>
> jfultz at wolfram.com
>
> User Interface Group
>
> Wolfram Research, Inc.

Comment: `NotebookConvert` is not working for me to convert the version 2.2 `.ma` files. I load `Developer` and use `SetDirectory` to make the old notebook's directory the current working directory. If I then evaluate an expression of the form `NotebookConvert["old.ma"]` (where file `old.ma` exists in that directory), I get no error but nothing seems to happen -- I find no `old.nb` in that directory or anywhere else.

Comment: @murray Please share with us some of your problematic notebooks in order to allow us to test the possible solutions. You can use any filehosting service for this, for example https://www.sendspace.com/ or https://www.solidfiles.com/

Comment: Two such Version 2.2 `.ma` files on which Version 10.4.1's `Developer`NotebookConvert` seems to do nothing may be downloaded from https://www.solidfiles.com/v/y8k22ZqKXAZvM

Comment: On my system (Windows 7 x64) evaluation of ``Developer`NotebookConvert["FIRSTLAB.MA"]`` crashes FrontEnd both with version 8.0.4 and 10.4.1. Obviously this functionality is currently broken. From the other side version 5.2 on my system opens these files and converts them without any difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

How to save Older Mathematica Files With The .ma Extension.

In order to use them I needed to convert some older (1995) mathematica files I found in a CD in a used book so that they would run on 11.1. They had extension ".ma".

To do this I did the following.
1) Download the Mathematica CDF program. To find this look under resources in the Mathematica start window.
2) Place the files to be modified in a there own directory.
3) Change windows folder options to show all extensions.
4) Change the ma extension to nb. With my ".ma" files if I did not do this CDF would not read them.
5) Read the files into the CDF program.
6) In the edit drop down choose Select All then Copy.
7) Open a new notebook in Mathematica and paste the text into.
8) Save the file. I added the word reworked at the end of the filename but before the extension. Example Chpt1.ma-->Chpt1.nb->>into CDF->>copied text to new file in Mathematica -->  saved as Chpt1reworked.nb.

There maybe problems as some instructions have changed, but this will get you started.

Good Luck